# Как ссылаться из класса на другой класс?

Tags: python, классы

**Бинарное дерево:**

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class Tree: 
    def insert():
        pass
```

Есть класс Node с параметрами и класс Tree. Как с Tree ссылаться на класс Node чтобы функция insert() принимало параметры с класса Node?

**Правка:**
Сделал ссылку через наследование:

```
class Tree(Node):
    def addItem(self, data):
        if data < self.data:
            if self.left is None:
                self.left = Tree(data)
            else:
                self.left.addItem(data)
        elif data > self.data:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = Tree(data)
            else:
                self.right.addItem(data)
```

Comment: Но ведь в `Tree` наверняка будет много `Node`, а не одна? Значит тут именно наследование вряд ли имеет смысл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

есть класс, есть экземпляр класса

в первом случае - это чертеж дома, во втором - построенный дом

в первом случае вам будет нужно наследование:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class Tree(Node):
    def insert():
        pass
```

, во втором - передача экземпляра в качестве параметра метода:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class Tree: 
    def insert(node_element: Node):
        pass
```

Что конкретно вам нужно то?

Comment: Сделал через наследование (добавил код в тему). Но считается ли такой код корректным, а именно, в функции addItem - self.left = Tree(data) ссылаясь на класс Tree, а не на Node? В дальнейшем не будет проблем с этим. Сейчас такой код работает, выдает правильный результат